# How do I get the auto-layout to work correctly in xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am attempting to get the auto-layout to work correctly. For some reason, when I change the size of the device, all of the images and buttons are out of place and don't resize at all. This is true for the 3.5 inch screen, as well as the ipad retina. When I run the simulator, the app shows exactly how it shows in storyboard. Auto-layout should be resizing everything so that this does not happen. please help!

[image: iPhone3gsImage][image: iphone4.7Image]

Comment: Have you set the height/width of your labels and images?

Comment: Absolutely, I have tried to change and set all of the constraints to the point that I get all blue lines around every button and image. It still cuts off half of the screen once it is scaled down to 3.5in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that constraints don't scale. When you set a constraint height to 200 it will always be 200, even if the screen is only 100 high. So what you need to do is try to set constraints that makes the size dynamically rather then set the constraint height/widths yourself.

For instance, on your first label under the `UIImageView` set the constraints leading and trailing to 20, then set the label constraint to center horizontally on the `UIImageView`. No other constraints for the label. This will cause the label to shrink in width since its set to be 20 away from each side. The height will not change since there is nothing "pushing" it to shrink since you are missing a few constraints, but basically you need to use the top, bottom, leading, and trailing, constraints to the `UIViewController` view in order to "scale" the elements.

If you'd like I could try and set the constraints for you if you upload the project and you can then watch how I did.

### Edit

It's hard for me to know what kind of behaviour you'd want, but something has to scale or change size in your set up. The easiest would be to resize the UIImageView. It's basically impossible to make it look exactly alike in every screen size, though, so you'll have to play around a bit with constraints until you understand how they work and how to adjust them according to what you want. One way is to create the layout you want and then connect them to code and scale them depending on size of the screen (this is a bit of a pain, I did that in a project recently and it took a bit of time and effort).

The easiest approach is to make the UIImageView to change its size when it needs to, and add extra space in the bottom. Here is a demo project I threw together earlier. Download [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99198804/ConstraintsDemo.zip)

Comment: I'm trying this out now. If I am successful, I will let you know!

Comment: I'm about ready to take you up on your offer if its still on the table. I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: @DarrylNunn it's hard for me to know the behaviour you want. Check my edit for a demo project to use as a reference.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It looks like I was missing the "<=" instead of "=" in the constraints. Bravo

Comment: @ClockWise is my constraints will work when reduce the image width and height  right? download link is missing . can i get your sample project

Comment: @SubinKKuriakose what you posted as an answer will not work, no. Since the content view has different size depending on device you need to account for it in your constraints. Simply setting the height and width constraint will only cause them to be the same size no matter what device - which will result in unwanted behaviour. The link to my sample project is working, I just clicked and downloaded. Look in the edit in my answer.

Comment: yea i got your project...just beginner level knowledge i have .. thanks

Comment: @ClockWise I've hit a wall. Thought that everything was working correctly, but it seems as though nothing works once I take a look at it on the ipad retina. everything goes back to being all screwy. been working on this all day, and I cant get it right.

Comment: @DarrylNunn I've actually never made an app that uses both iPhone and iPad I have to confess. In this case it might be a bit hard to use the same constraints since the sizes varies immensely between the two platforms. You might want to check up on size classes instead. Basically you specify constraints for a specific size class which will only be in effect if the device used is of that size. So you can set constraints for iPad and for iPhone separately. You can even set size classes for each specific iPhone device if you want. I've never done that either though, so I'm not much help here :(

Comment: Thats the thing...its not for ipad, only iPhone. However, when I submitted the app, it was rejected by apple saying that it must fit the 3.5in iphone screen, which is also used to scale up on ipad. I had been developing my app for the newer iphones the entire time. Its only once I submitted it that I found out it doesn't fit the smaller iphone screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Profile pic

1) first you set the profile pic image center horizontal to the content view

2) set height and width for the profile pic

3)set top space constraints to content view

Change Profile pic label

1)set central horizontal to profile pic

2)set width and height

3)set vertical space between profile pic

Challenges Accepted label

1) set vertical space to profile pic label

2) set Leading space to container

3) set height

and do same for the below two content . i didnt tested. check it and try

Comment: Tried it out. The size of image doesn't change when the screen size changes which causes an issue since its sized for iphone 6. When i go down to iphone 3gs, it cuts off half of the screen. I am unable to see the labels.

Comment: in your story board Wany Hany   (layout)  ?

Comment: I change the sizes in the storyboard, but then I run the simulator to see how things look

Answer (score 0):

After a long night of struggling, I figured out what I needed to do. I was setting the individual view controllers to have a simulated size of 4.7inch. This made it hard for the constraints to scale across all devices since I was setting the constraints for a specific screen size. However, this would be the way to go if using size classes.

I solved my issue by using the standard 600 X 600 canvas that is available before choosing a specific size. This way, I was able to set constraints that scaled down for the smaller screens, and scaled up for the larger/HD screens. This works perfectly with auto-layout. Hope that helps someone!